# Cómo modificar ancho de columna con Apache POI

Tags: java

Básicamente necesito cambiar el ancho de las columnas, pero que no sea en base al contenido de las mismas columnas, como ya lo hace la función `autoSizeColumn`, sino alguna otra manera para hacerlo individualmente a cada celda por código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [setColumnWidth(int, int)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%252)

con ello seria suficiente para asignar el ancho de la columna.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a implementarla. La he usado, pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Escribe la parte del codigo que no te esta funcionando correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he usado este código y me sirvio.

```
    //creamos el libro
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
    //creamos la hoja
    Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("nombreHoja"));
    //iniciamos variables
    int numeroColumna = 4;
    int tamano = 12000;
    //damos tamano a la columna
    sheet.setColumnWidth(numeroColumna, tamano);
```

si tienes algún problema avísame.